# How to make a text change you from one screen to another

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

how to make a text change you from one screen to another.
Not button, text, I just need to know what to add in the .java

Comment: You need to add code.

Comment: Might be just me, but I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..Dear user dont expect stack overflow members to do coding for your ideas..Kindly take some effort in writing codes and ask SO members if you have any doubts in the code..

Comment: Do you mean some text the user has typed, or a text (SMS) message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to changing from one screen (activity) to another by typing something and not by clicking a button. If that is the case use TextWatcher and on change check for your string (or command) and move to next screen. Something like.

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        if("second".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1 : pass text from screen 1 to screen 2
step 2 : in OnCreate() method of screen 2 , recieve and change the text according to your requirement
```

but Personally i feel you want to display some screen info for every screen is it ??

Comment: @Markab : did it Help , what was your exact requirement ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a TextView instead of a Button...in that case, make your TextView clickable:true in your xml and then you can set an onClickListener to it. 
Either by TextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener....) in java, or by android:onClick in xml. Just like for a button.